# How to parse a GVariant type variable of type '(a{oa{sa{sv}}})'?

Tags: c

here is my code for C:

```c
    GVariant *result = NULL;
    GError *error = NULL;

        
    
    result = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(connection, 
                                         dbus_server_name, 
                                         RN_DBUS_CTC_OBJ_PORTMAPPING, 
                                         RN_DBUS_CTC_IF_OBJMANAGER, 
                                         "GetManagedObjects",
                                         NULL, //parameters
                                         G_VARIANT_TYPE("(a{oa{sa{sv}}})"), 
                                         G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE, 
                                         RN_DBUS_TIMEOUT * 1000, 
                                         NULL, 
                                         &error);

    if (error != NULL) {
        rn_logd("call method getAllObjects error: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        return -1;
    }
```

I want to extract the data content of 'result,' but I've encountered some issues.

Below is my try, and I apologize for the inclusion of some debug logging functions. This part of the code is based on ChatGPT's answer, but it didn't work quite well. The result shows only '1.1', and it hasn't entered the while loop.

I expect to correctly extract all the attributes.

```c
    GVariantIter outer_iter, inner_iter, property_iter;
    gchar *object_path, *interface_name, *property_name;
    GVariant *inner_dict, *property_dict, *property_val;



    rn_logd("1.1");
    while (g_variant_iter_next(&outer_iter, "{oa{sa{sv}}}", &object_path, &inner_dict)) {
        rn_logd("Object Path: %s\n", object_path);

        gboolean use_type_annotate = TRUE;

        gchar *variant_str  = g_variant_print(inner_dict, use_type_annotate);

        rn_logd("str:%s", variant_str);

        rn_logd("item:%s has type '%s' ", object_path, g_variant_get_type_string(inner_dict));

        g_variant_iter_init(&inner_iter, inner_dict);
        rn_logd("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
        while (g_variant_iter_next(&inner_iter, "{&s@a{sv}}", &interface_name, &property_dict)) {
            rn_logd("\tInterface: %s\n", interface_name);

            g_variant_iter_init(&property_iter, property_dict);
            while (g_variant_iter_next(&property_iter, "{&s@v}", &property_name, &property_val)) {
                rn_logd("\t\tProperty Name: %s, Value: ", property_name);
                // print_variant(property_val);
                g_variant_unref(property_val);
            }
            g_variant_unref(property_dict);
        }
        g_variant_unref(inner_dict);
    }


    g_variant_unref(result);
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting.  Edit your question and include type definitions for every type you are using (if non standard type) so we can help you.